# Making a calculator but I am receiving compiling errors

Tags: java, calculator

I am teaching myself Java and started to make a calculator but I'm running into two errors when I try and run the code.

I was thinking about implementing a `WHILE` loop with the characters to create a loop but it did not seem to work. Really burnt out and I thought this was a good place to ask.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double numberOne = 0;
        double numberTwo = 0;
        String operatorInput;
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
       numberOne = myInput.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
       numberTwo = myInput.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the operation you wish to perform (/, *, -, +): ");
       operatorInput = myInput.nextLine();

       double result = calculate(numberOne, numberTwo, operatorInput, myInput);

       System.out.printf("The result is: %.2f%n", result);

       myInput.close();
    }

    public static double calculate(double numberOne, double numberTwo, String operatorInput, Scanner myInput)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            switch (operatorInput)
            {
                case("/"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return divideNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                case("*"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return multiplyNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                case("+"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return addNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                case("-"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return subtractNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                default: 
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    System.out.print("Enter the operation you wish to perform (/, *, -, +): ");
                    operatorInput = myInput.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static double divideNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
    {
        return numberOne / numberTwo;
    }
    public static double multiplyNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
    {
        return numberOne * numberTwo;
    }
    public static double addNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
    {
        return numberOne + numberTwo;
    }
    public static double subtractNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
    {
        return numberOne - numberTwo;
    }
}
```

```
Calculator.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
       operatorInput = input.nextChar();
                            ^
  symbol:   method nextChar()
  location: variable input of type Scanner
Calculator.java:55: error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to double
                return null;
                       ^
```

Comment: Well, there is no `nextChar()` method in Scanner class... Use other ones available like `next()` and then on returned string `charAt(0)`.

Comment: a `double` primitive can never be `null`. Perhaps throw an exception if none of your operators are matched

Comment: How would I implement ```charAt(0)``` in my return string exactly? Since there is no ```input.nextChar()``` how would I properly call for the next character in my ```operatorInput```?

Comment: Reimeus, I will give that a shot. Thank you so much!

Comment: I went ahead an placed ```operatorInput = nextString().charA(0);``` This eliminated the first error. I am now looking to fix the null issue with an exception brought up by Reimeus.

Comment: If your issue is solved, consider using the "Answers" section below to post a detailed write-up on how you managed to fix your issue - it will greatly benefit any future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using a `while(true)` on top of the `switch`. Also, I could not use the `nextChar()` because it wasn't supported by the scanner. I was able to fix this by creating a scanner called `myInput`. This allowed me to continue on passed me character selection. Once that was done I was able to break the loop with that scanner `myInput.close();` refer to updated code above. Thanks again, everyone!

```
 double numberOne = 0;
        double numberTwo = 0;
        String operatorInput;
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
       numberOne = myInput.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
       numberTwo = myInput.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the operation you wish to perform (/, *, -, +): ");
       operatorInput = myInput.nextLine();

       double result = calculate(numberOne, numberTwo, operatorInput, myInput);

       System.out.printf("The result is: %.2f%n", result);

       myInput.close();
    }

    public static double calculate(double numberOne, double numberTwo, String operatorInput, Scanner myInput)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            switch (operatorInput)
            {
                case("/"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return divideNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                case("*"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return multiplyNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                case("+"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return addNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                case("-"):
                {
                    myInput.close();
                    return subtractNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
                }
                default: 
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    System.out.print("Enter the operation you wish to perform (/, *, -, +): ");
                    operatorInput = myInput.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change double primitive type to Double object to be able to return null value.
also you can convert operatorInput to string and read it as input.next() 
here's example for what changes I suggest:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double numberOne = 0;
    double numberTwo = 0;
    String operatorInput;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
   numberOne = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
   numberTwo = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print("Enter the operation you wish to perform (/, *, -, +): ");
   operatorInput = input.next();
   System.out.println(calculate(numberOne, numberTwo,operatorInput));

}



public static Double calculate(double numberOne, double numberTwo, String operatorInput)
{
    switch (operatorInput)
    {
        case("/"):
        {
            return divideNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
        }
        case("*"):
        {
            return multiplyNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
        }
        case("+"):
        {
            return addNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
        }
        case("-"):
        {
            return subtractNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
        }
        default: 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public static double divideNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
{
    return numberOne / numberTwo;
}
public static double multiplyNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
{
    return numberOne * numberTwo;
}
public static double addNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
{
    return numberOne + numberTwo;
}
public static double subtractNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo)
{
    return numberOne - numberTwo;
}
```

}